# How do I add dependencies to this header file

Tags: makefile, g++

Here is a simple header file for six different programs. This Makefile used to work just fine, but then I changed the programs to include other implementation files.  This Makefile needs to get changed so that if the implementation files change the files that include those implementation files get recompiled.

```
all: load list show add delete btree
%: %.cpp
    g++ $< -g -o $@
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the -MM option of gcc to create dependency files, and then include those into your Makefile.

```
TARGETS = load list show add delete btree
all: $(TARGETS)
%: %.cpp
    g++ $< -g -o $@ -MM -MF $@.dd
    sed "s/$@\.o:/$@:/" $@.dd > $@.d
    -@rm $@.dd

DEPS=$(TARGETS:%=%.d)
-include $(DEPS)
```

The `sed` line is present to change the dependency file from `load.o: load.c` to `load: load.c`.

Comment: When I do g++ -MM list.cpp, I get the following output: list.o: list.cpp bt.h insert.c btio.c btutil.c Lab2.cpp. What am I supposed to do with that? It doesn't actually create anything.

Comment: You don't need to run it directly - the %: %.cpp rule does that. The rule converts that line to a set of .d files that are then included in the makefile

Comment: `-MM` generates this output, and `-MF` redirects it in a file (ending in .dd). The next line runs `sed` to slightly modify, and rename it in `.d`. These last `.d` files are included in the Makefile, and tells make what file depend on which other.

Comment: When I run make, I get the following error: Makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: You have to use real tabs and not spaces to indent the commands.

Comment: That fixed it but now all that happens is it creates files that don't do anything.

Comment: These .d files are included in the Makefile (see last line: -include). They are used by make to know about dependencies and to rebuild files when needed.